# why horizontal application create vertical activity after onPause()

Tags: android, screen-orientation

My app is supposed to be only horizontal. In **AndroidManifest.xml** I have `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`. 
But when I press Power button (turn off device) and then press Power button again (turn on device) I can see some problems. By debug process I can see that my application goes through the following steps:

> *press Power button->onPause()->onSaveInstance()->onStop()->onDestroy()->onCreate()->onStart()->onResume()->onPause(). And I can see that HORIZONTAL activity was created but its size is equal to vertical screen!*

> Then:
>   *press Power button->onResume()->onPause()->onSaveInstante()->onStop()->onDestroy()->onCreate()->onStart()->onResume().
>   And needed HORIZONTAL activity was created.*

Where is my mistake?  Should I set screen size at first anywhere?

I understood the problem: when I press Power button orientation is changed(lock screen is in portrait by default) which is causing calling onCreate().
 
So what should I do?

Comment: use this in manifest not sensorLandscape ..android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Comment: It doesn't work( And can you say me why new activity is need to be created before Pause?

Comment: check have you change orientaion programatically anywhere in the code?

Comment: write this in onCreate before setContentView setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); // Make to run your application only in LANDSCAPE mode

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: try code i mentioned above in comments

Comment: Oh, i am sorry, I see that I must correct my question

Comment: sorry, no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" solved the problem. A piece of cake.